# How do I find projects in specific source language in Launchpad Translations?

Tags: launchpad, language-support, translation, localization

I want to participate in Launchpad Translations. I'm an expert in Spanish and German.

Is it somehow possible to find projects that are originally written in either Spanish or German and have to be translated first into English or any other language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally very rare. Projects are typically written using the POSIX C locale (which is en_US in US-ASCII), and are then translated into other languages. And I don't know of any good way to find things based on the native language of the developers.

The translations system also generally expects that the default language being translated from is POSIX C.